# Some help with some Python code

Tags: python, ctypes

Can anyone tell me why num_chars and num_rows have to be the same?

```
from ctypes import *

num_chars = 8
num_rows = 8
num_cols = 6

buffer = create_string_buffer (num_chars*num_rows*num_cols+num_chars)

for char in range(num_chars):
        for row in range(num_rows):
                for col in range(num_cols):
                        if char == num_chars-1 and col == num_cols-1:
                                buffer[row*num_rows*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row] = '|'
                                buffer[row*num_rows*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row+1] = '\n'
                        elif col == num_cols-1:
                                buffer[row*num_rows*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row] = '|'
                        else:
                                buffer[row*num_rows*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row] = ('.', '*')[char>row]

print buffer.value
```

The output

```
.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|
```

And now changing num_chars to 15.

```
.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, I thought the output would be enough. You have to play with this and plug in different numbers to see what it is doing. I'll do that and plug in the output.

Comment: Why are you using ctypes for this?

Comment: For a mutable character buffer.

Comment: The source and the output is not sufficient as You have stated that it's not working right. You want us to fix it but You don't say what exacly it should do, only that it does for the first example and doesn't for the second. PLEEEEASE be more descriptive. Help us help You.

Comment: If you can't understand the question, don't bother trying to give an answer I suppose. I can't be any more descriptive than providing the code and answering specific questions about it. I can't read your minds and predict your questions. The code barely makes sense to me as it is.

Comment: If you can't tell us what it's meant to do or why you ask "why do num_chars and num_rows have to be the same", then we can't tell you anything useful. For example, who or what says num_chars and num_rows have to be the same?

Comment: I'll just assume from now on that people can't run the code. I should have started it off with some output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said you are using ctypes because you want mutable char buffer for this. But you can get the output you want from list comprehension

```
num_chars = 5
num_rows = 8
empty = ['.' * num_chars]
full = ['*' * num_chars]
print '\n'.join(
    '|'.join(empty * (i + 1) + (num_rows - i - 1) * full)
    for i in xrange(num_rows)
)

.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****
.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****
.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|*****|*****
.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|*****|*****
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|*****|*****
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|*****|*****
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|*****
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....
```

**EDIT**

I'll show you how you can use list comprehensions to draw whatever char bitmap you want to draw. The idea is simple. Build a boolean array with True in the places you want to print the character and False otherwise. And just use the 'or' trick to print the right character. This example will build a chess like board. You can use the same concept to draw any shape you want.

```
rows = 5
cols = 6
char = '#'
empty = '.'
bitmap = [[ (i + j)%2 == 0 for i in xrange(cols)] for j in xrange(rows)]
print '\n'.join(
    '|'.join(bitmap[j][i] * char or empty for i in xrange(cols))
    for j in xrange(rows)
)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by this. I don't get the same output. Why isn't num_cols used? Yet you have that many cols in your characters.

Comment: If you copy and paste my code it'll produce the exact output in the answer

Comment: What do you mean by num_cols? you need to be more descriptive. I'm assuming that num_chars means the number of chars in every |.....|

Comment: WelI get this:
........|********|********|********|********|********|********|********
........|........|********|********|********|********|********|********
........|........|........|********|********|********|********|********
........|........|........|........|********|********|********|********
........|........|........|........|........|********|********|********
........|........|........|........|........|........|********|********
........|........|........|........|........|........|........|********
........|........|........|........|........|........|........|........

Comment: Bah. Well the characters are 8 spaces wide.

Comment: So by num_chars you don't really mean the number of chars. You mean the number of columns in a row?

Comment: Please explain in words how would you like the program to work.

Comment: A char is broken at the |. Chars are listed from left to right. Each char is 8x5, or 8x6 including the |. The last position has a newline character. Your code doesn't have the 5 character wide characters when I use it. I get 8 spaces wide.

Comment: Would you run my answer again? My program takes different numbers of chars as an input

Comment: That got it. Confusing. I changed one line to the following: '|'.join(empty * (i + 1) + (num_cols - i - 1) * full). And now it works exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks man.

Comment: I would still like to know what's wrong with my code however. hehe :)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that my original intentions were to be able to create character bitmaps. I don't see how I can do that with this, although it's a really neat trick.

Comment: Here you go, I updated the example to show you how to create character bitmaps with list comprehension. Lists are mutables you can change them the way you like.

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely going to be reading on list comprehension tonight. Thanks for the tips. I'll most certainly be using them.

Answer (score 1):

There we go. I had row*num_rows instead of row*num_chars I must need a Dr Pepper. And by the way, this wasn't homework. It's for an LCD project.

```
num_chars = 10
num_rows = 8
num_cols = 6

buffer = create_string_buffer (num_chars*num_rows*num_cols+num_chars)

for char in range(num_chars):
        for row in range(num_rows):
                for col in range(num_cols):
                        if char == num_chars-1 and col == num_cols-1:
                                buffer[row*num_chars*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row] = '|'
                                buffer[row*num_chars*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row+1] = '\n'
                        elif col == num_cols-1:
                                buffer[row*num_chars*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row] = '|'
                        else:
                                buffer[row*num_chars*num_cols+char*num_cols+col+row] = ('.', '*')[char>row]

print repr(buffer.raw)
print buffer.value
```